# Capture-avoiding substitution function -- Lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, substitution, lambda-calculus

I am trying to write a function that performs capture-avoiding substitution in Lambda calculus. The code compiles but does not spit out the correct answer. I've written what I expect the code to do, is my comprehension correct?

For example, I should get the following output for this input (`numeral 0` is the Church numeral 0)

> ```
> *Main> substitute "b" (numeral 0) example    -- \a. \x. ((\y. a) x) b
> \c. \a. (\a. c) a (\f. \x. x)
>
> -- The incorrect result I actually got
> \c. \c. (\f. \x. x) (x (\b. a))
> ```

NB `\y` is renamed to `\a` due to the substitution `(\y.a)[N/b]` (I think I have this covered in the code I have written, but please let me know if I am wrong.)

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term
  --  deriving Show

instance Show Term where
  show = pretty

example :: Term        -- \a. \x. ((\y. a) x) b
example = Lambda "a"
            (Lambda "x" (Apply (Apply (Lambda "y" (Variable "a")) 
                                      (Variable "x")) 
                               (Variable "b")))

pretty :: Term -> String
pretty = f 0
    where
      f i (Variable x) = x
      f i (Lambda x m) = if i /= 0 then "(" ++ s ++ ")" else s 
                         where s = "\\" ++ x ++ ". " ++ f 0 m 
      f i (Apply  n m) = if i == 2 then "(" ++ s ++ ")" else s 
                         where s = f 1 n ++ " " ++ f 2 m

substitute :: Var -> Term -> Term -> Term

substitute x n (Variable y)  
    --if y = x, then leave n alone   
    | y == x    = n
    -- otherwise change to y  
    | otherwise = Variable y

substitute x n (Lambda y m)
    --(\y.M)[N/x] = \y.M if y = x 
    | y == x    = Lambda y m
    --otherwise \z.(M[z/y][N/x]), where `z` is a fresh variable name 
    --generated by the `fresh` function, `z` must not be used in M or N, 
    --and `z` cannot be equal `x`. The `used` function checks if a 
    --variable name has been used in `Lambda y m`   
    | otherwise = Lambda newZ newM
                  where newZ = fresh(used(Lambda y m))
                        newM = substitute x n m          

substitute x n (Apply  m2 m1) = Apply newM2 newM1
    where newM1 = substitute x n m2
          newM2 = substitute x n m1

used :: Term -> [Var]
used (Variable n) = [n]
used (Lambda n t) = merge [n] (used t)
used (Apply t1 t2) = merge (used t1) (used t2)

variables :: [Var]
variables =  [l:[] | l <- ['a'..'z']] ++ 
             [l:show x | x <- [1..], l <- ['a'..'z']]

filterFreshVariables :: [Var] -> [Var] -> [Var]
filterFreshVariables lst = filter ( `notElem` lst)

fresh :: [Var] -> Var
fresh lst = head (filterFreshVariables lst variables)

recursiveNumeral :: Int -> Term
recursiveNumeral i
  | i == 0 = Variable "x"
  | i > 0 = Apply(Variable "f")(recursiveNumeral(i-1))

numeral :: Int -> Term
numeral i = Lambda "f" (Lambda "x" (recursiveNumeral i))

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge (x : xs) (y : ys)
  | x < y = x : merge xs (y : ys)
  | otherwise = y : merge (x : xs) ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
```

Comment: You showed what you wanted the code to do, can you also say what the code actually does?

Comment: Also add the missing the definitions of `fresh` and `used` to make the example compilable.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I've added fresh and used

Comment: Please include the actual definition of `numeral` for clarity.

Comment: Also, what does `n.b \y` mean? That looks like a fragment of ... something. But it's not a well-formed expression.

Comment: @dfeuer I've interpreted it as "NB `\y` ..." when I edited.

Comment: @dfeuer I've added numeral. I meant note well \y...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part in `substitute x n (Lambda y m)` is not correct:

- the comment says "`z` must not be used in `M` or `N`", but there is nothing preventing that. `newZ` could be a variable in `n`, which leads to a problematic capture
- the substitution `z/y` has not been done

```hs
    | otherwise = Lambda newZ newM
                  where newZ = fresh(used(Lambda y m))
                        newM = substitute x n m
```

Fix:

1. "`z` must not be used in `M` or `N`":

```hs
newZ = fresh(used m `merge` used n)
```

2. "`M[z/y][N/x]`":

```hs
newM = substitute x n (substitute y (Variable newZ) m)
```

Put together:

```hs
    | otherwise = Lambda newZ newM
    where
      newZ = fresh(used m `merge` used n)
      newM = substitute x n (substitute y (Variable newZ) m)
```

Note that refreshing *all* bindings as done above makes it difficult to understand the result and to debug substitution. Actually `y` only needs to be refreshed if `y` is in `n`. Otherwise you can keep `y`, adding this clause:

```hs
    | y `notElem` used n = Lambda y (substitute x n m)
```

Another idea would be to modify `fresh` to pick a name similar to the old one, e.g., by appending numbers until one doesn't clash.

---

There is still a bug I missed: `newZ` should also not be equal to `x` (the variable originally being substituted).

```
-- substitute [a -> \f. \x. x] in (\g. g), should be (\g. g)
ghci> substitute "a" (numeral 0) (Lambda "g" (Variable "g"))
\a. \g. \x. x
```

Two ways to address this:

1. add `x` to the set of variables to exclude `newZ` from:

   ```
   newZ = fresh ([x] `merge` used m `merge` used n)
   ```
2. if you think about it, this bug only manifests itself when `x` is not in `m`, in which case there is nothing to substitute, so another way is to add one more branch skipping the work:

   ```
   | x `notElem` used m = Lambda y m
   ```

---

Put together:

```hs
substitute x n (Lambda y m)
    --(\y.M)[N/x] = \y.M if y = x 
    | y == x    = Lambda y m
    | x `notElem` used m = Lambda y m
    | y `notElem` used n = Lambda y (substitute x n m)
    | otherwise = Lambda newZ newM
                  where newZ = fresh(used m `merge` used n)
                        newM = substitute x n (substitute y (Variable newZ) m)
```

Output

```
ghci> example
\a. \x. (\y. a) x b
ghci> numeral 0
\f. \x. x
ghci> substitute "b" (numeral 0) example
\a. \c. (\y. a) c (\f. \x. x)
```

---

Note: I haven't tried to prove this code correct (exercise for the reader: define "correct"), there may still be bugs I missed. There must be some course about lambda calculus that has all the details and pitfalls but I haven't bothered to look.

Comment: Please could you clarify your answer? I don't understand your point about newZ being a variable in n? cheers

Comment: You defined `newZ` to be a variable that is not used in `y` or `m`, but that doesn't mean it can't have been used in `n`, which can lead to an incorrect substitution.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, but I still get the same output:                   `where newZ = if fresh(used(Lambda y m)) == head(used(n)) || head(used(n)) == x then fresh(used(n)) else fresh(used(Lambda y m))`

Comment: I added a fix in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the output should be `*Main> substitute "b" (numeral 0) example \c. \a. (\a. c) a (\f. \x. x)`, not `\a. \c. (\y. a) c (\f. \x. x)`, why are the `a` and `c` incorrect?

Comment: These two terms are alpha-equivalent, so the difference shouldn't matter. If you think it does, then you need to give much more precise requirements about the substitution function, that explains precisely when and how to pick fresh variables. It's not sufficient to just say "z should be fresh in N and M".

Comment: Ah I see, z can also not be equal to x. Does this line in your code accomplish this?    `newM = substitute x n (substitute y (Variable newZ) m)`

Comment: No it doesn't, that's one more bug. I updated my answer with a fix.